# Regex to check for duplicate space characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to write a regex to validate a text entry. The text must be between 5 and 16 characters (a-Z plus hyphen, underscore and space). This is fine but it must also check that there are not any consecutive spaces.

e.g.

```
hello        // PASS
hello there  // PASS
hi there you // PASS
hello  there // FAIL - two spaces between hello and there
```

Comment: What about consecutive hyphens and consecutive underscores?  What about runs of two or more kinds, like `hello- _there`?  What about spaces, hyphens or underscores at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: @Alan - just consecutive spaces anywhere in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
/^(?!.*  )[-a-z_ ]{5,16}\z/i
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not validate any of the examples when I test it. I have also tested it at http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html and it fails there too. Any ideas?

Comment: @TheFlowerGuy, try without the delimiters and flag: `^(?!.*  )[-a-z_ ]{5,16}\z` or `^(?!.*  )[-a-z_ ]{5,16}$`

Comment: Are you working with Java then?  That's what RegexPlanet uses.  Please tag the question with the language/flavor you're using.

Comment: @TheFlowerGuy, it works just fine at that site for me. As Bart said, the regex is what inside the delimiters: `^(?!.*  )[-a-z_ ]{5,16}\z`

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had tried it without the delimiters as well but obviously not. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In Java I would go with

```
"  |[^\\p{L}_ -]"
```

(`"` isn't part of the regex).
If the string matches this regex then it fails.
I would check the size separately in an if sentence (faster that way).

If you want to do it in some language without Unicode properties:

```
\s\s|[^A-Za-z_ -]
```

Comment: if you use the block style of formatting as I did, the whitespace is preserved.  Also, you should mention that this regex needs to be applied with the `find()` method, not `matches()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
One should note that this solution is much faster than the above one.
This solution will check one character in best case scenario (incorrect character at start or 2 spaces) and all characters in worst case scenario (correct string). Solution with negative lookahead (?!.*) (the one above) will always check all characters (best case scenario - two spaces at the end) and it will check all characters twice (worst case scenario - correct string or 2 spaces at the start).

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
^([\w-_]+([\s]{0,1})[\w-_]+)$
```

Matches these

```
hello
hello there
hi there
he-llo
he_las test
```

And **not** these

```
hello  there
hello     there
```

Comment: Fails to match `hi there you`; incorrectly matches `123 456`; allows tabs, linefeeds, and other whitespace characters; and doesn't validate the length.  Also, instead of making the space optional, you should group it with the following part and make the group optional: `^(?=.{5,16}$)[A-Za-z_-]+(?: [A-Za-z_-]+)*$`