# How to dynamically remove extra space in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

How can I make  extra space be removed in a string in Javascript ?

For example

I have a string the following string

```
var string ="how    are you today";
```

I would like to know what function or trick I could use to dynamically remove extra space in strings in Javascript so that I can have `var string ="how are you today";` instead ..

How could I do this ?

Comment: I would use a regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150037/regex-to-check-for-duplicate-space-characters

Comment: I know it's just an example but even for an example you shouldn't use a variable name like `string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets assume you have
`var myString ="how    are you today";`

If you just want to handle spaces:

`myString.replace(/ +/g, ' ');`

If you want to replace tabs and new lines as well:

`myString.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`

Please note that this does not change the value of myString, but rather return a new string with the spaces removed. So to save this result you would do, for example:

`var fixedString = myString.replace(/ +/g, ' ');`

Comment: @kennebec Right. Corrected my answer :)

Comment: @OpherV where is the variable name of the string represented in your example ?  if my string variable name is sentence .. how would you remove all the spaces in it .. sentence.replace(/ +g, ' '); ?